# DocumentFile.canWrite(), DocumentFile.exists() - poor performance (takes too much CPU time) when working with local built-in phone storage (not cloud)

Tags: android, android-file, storage-access-framework, android-document-provider

I'm not really sure but why the following `DocumentFile`'s `exist` and `canWrite` functions takes too much CPU time compare to `File` when working with built-in phone external storage (it's not a cloud)?

It's like **~8-30** ms per function call. It should be at least the same (the same storage).

For `File` it usually doesn't go higher 10 ms and average is usually less than 10 ms.

Tested on Samsung S10 (Android 12) and on Samsung S22 Ultra (Android 13) and still performance is quite bad when using SAF

**Updated** omg, there is another function which works even worse - `DocumentFile.findFile()`, it basically takes ages though the folder contains 0-2 files, insane...

**Updated 2**: yes, never use `DocumentFile`, do all operations with `DocumentContract` with your Uris but still even this one needs some optimization in the code to not be used a lot (like implementation of `listFiles` and so on), also if you know that file at the specific location and has the specific name then you can combine your own Uri instead of trying to get them with `ContentResolver` which is eating CPU as hell

**Updated 3**: Google is a joke - https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_support/blob/d4003121f8a9f65ee072f4e32d21f4a97de0227e/documentfile/src/main/java/androidx/documentfile/provider/TreeDocumentFile.java#L144

```
@Override
public DocumentFile[] listFiles() {
    final ContentResolver resolver = mContext.getContentResolver();
    final Uri childrenUri = DocumentsContract.buildChildDocumentsUriUsingTree(mUri,
            DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(mUri));
    final ArrayList<Uri> results = new ArrayList<>();

    Cursor c = null;
    try {
        c = resolver.query(childrenUri, new String[] {
                DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_DOCUMENT_ID }, null, null, null);
```

From https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/bbejc4/caveats_with_documentfile/

> For example, an app might use DocumentFile.listFiles() to get the
> files in a folder. While the individual call for it isn't that bad,
> this call only gets the document ids for the children, and naively
> iterating over each of the children to get the name will be super
> expensive (as each child will need to query the content provider
> again, incurring the overhead costs again).
>
> To avoid this, content providers should be queried yourself and
> include the display name in the projection:

```
cursor = contentResolver.query(
    childrenUri, 
    new String[]{
        DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_DISPLAY_NAME,
        DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_MIME_TYPE,
        DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_DOCUMENT_ID}, 
    null,
    null,
    null);
```

Why did they even implemented this `DocumentFile` at all? I spent a lot of time to switch from `File` to `DocumentFile` and then I didn't expect the app to work so slow because of that piece of we know what.
If there was initially only `DocumentContract` I would use this one strait away... though it's also not perfect, for example if you want to find some file in folder then instead of getting all children and matching the name we can just concertante folder's Uri string + file's name we try to find and it will be much faster to try get the data of the file (size) directly or check if file exists

Comment: "It should be at least the same (the same storage)" -- it is unclear why you think that. The Storage Access Framework is a storage abstraction that relies on IPC. You can read the source code to `DocumentFile` to see what it does. Also, Stack Overflow is for programming questions: what is your question?

Comment: @CommonsWare well I could ask my question like: how to work with Files on Android because now it's impossible to work with them directly, and *Manage all files* is not available for all categories, though media players like VLC can still get this permission but not for all other apps of other developers until it's File Browser app. SAF is really bad at performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DocumentFile is about twenty times slower than the classic File class.

Use DocumentsContract instead.

It has about the same speed as File class.

Comment: yeah, already found info about `DocumentsContract` but still it's not that fast as well: https://github.com/davidliu/SAFTraversal/tree/master Users will hate our apps for such performance and battery discharging

Comment: Does `DocumentsContract` have the similar speed to `MediaStore` at least when fetching the data with `ContentResolver` for files?

Comment: yeah, at least with `DocumentsContract` I fill more safe now, it's much higher performance compare to `DocumentFile`

Comment: `Safe Access Framework` ?